# How can I pass std.stdio.File to another Thread via spawn?

Tags: multithreading, d

I am spawning a process using D's std.process.pipeProcess function, which gives me std.stdio.File structs for the process's input and output respectively. I need to be able to process output from the process, while at the same time process input from my own console.

Since there is no way to do a non-blocking readln() on a File struct, I need to spawn another thread to do a blocking wait for me, and then message pass it to the main thread via std.concurrency.

My problem is that when I pass it like this:

```
spawn(&myConsoleListenFunction, pipe.stdout)
```

The compiler says that that "Aliases to mutable thread-local data are not allowed". I know that means that I need to cast to shared, but I can't do that either because when I try to cast the File to shared I get this:

```
C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\phobos\std\concurrency.d(487,5): Error: non-shared method std.stdio.File.~this is not callable using a shared object
source\app.d(67,26): Error: template std.concurrency.spawn cannot deduce function from argument types !()(void function(File f, string prefix), shared(File), string), candidates are:
C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\phobos\std\concurrency.d(487,5):        std.concurrency.spawn(F, T...)(F fn, T args) if (isSpawnable!(F, T))
```

I also tried passing the File as __gshared, which results in the same "Alias" message.

Comment: Keep in mind that in D everything is *thread local* by default unless you want to explicitly change to *shared*. You should make something like `shared(File) pipe_stdout` and pass that to your thread.

Comment: @DejanLekic I tried that as I described above, I get those two compiler errors. Apparently you can't cast a File to shared (this is an std.stdio.File)

Comment: How did you pass it as __gshared ?

Comment: Not solving the issue, but you can create the pipe on the new thread, and communicate the results only.

Comment: Why do you need the process in the main thread? If you need to forward input, you could send it to the thread holding the process via std.concurrency.

Comment: @weltensturm that's the whole problem. I can't pass it to the other thread, unless I start it in the other thread, but then I also need it in the main thread.

Comment: @jython234 Yeah I got that. Start the process in the thread. Send whatever you need to write to the process to the thread via message, then it can do the writing.